# Listing/linking to contents of directory in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file

I have a set of static PDFs. I want to list them out on a rails page, with links to them.

What I need right now is how to trim the /public off the beginning of the path so the link will actually work.

Current code:

```
<h1>Listing letters</h1>
<table>
<ul>
<% @files = Dir.glob("public/files/*.pdf") %>
<% for file in @files %>
<% new_file = file.to_s %>
<% new_file = new_file.chomp("public/") %>
<li><%= link_to 'Letter', new_file %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</table>
```

However the links are still coming as

```
http://localhost:3000/public/files/document.pdf
```

when to work they need to be

```
http://localhost:3000/files/document.pdf
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<% Dir["public/files/*.pdf"].each do |file| %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Letter', file[/\/.*/] %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Far simpler than what I was trying. Thanks. You just saved me another hour :)

Answer (score 3):

The chomp method is used to remove someting at the **end** of the string ;) Use gsub instead.

```
new_file.gsub!('public', '')
```

or

```
new_file = new_file.gsub('public', '')
```

Comment: Getting closer! However doing <% new_file = new_file.delete "public/" %> is giving me a string with any of those letters in the path removed (ie fes/docment.pf)

Comment: Hmm true, sorry about that, try gsub. Added an example.