# Iterate over directory contents in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to embed a slideshow into a website that I'm building using rails. This requires me to make an unordered list of images inside a rails view. The point is that:

1) I want to have a directory, and have each image in the directory be included in the slideshow
2) I don't want the directory contents to be read in every request (this slideshow will be in the layout, and will be visible in all pages)
3) I want to be able to just drop a picture in the directory and the slideshow to pick it up

I was thinking of simply using Dir.glob as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804747/listing-linking-to-contents-of-directory-in-rails), but that violates requirement 2.

Then I thought I could make a list of the files present at the time the site starts, and store it in the application controller. But that violates requirement 3. Or I could somehow update this list on the fly.

Is there an easy way to do this? Am I making my life difficult for nothing? I mean I could just hard code the images.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a page cache as a solution for requirement 2, but then in step 3 you have to also delete page cache manually, or you may use something like [rb-inotify](https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify) for automation.